# Dispatching new action after global state changes in react redux

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

Lets say i have a form where user is about to click on combination of buttons.

Each button triggers an action of type T and reducer R then updates its state and new combination is rendered on a website.

Now comes the tricky part:
I have my business logic implemented in reducer which applies new state which is about to be rendered. What i need now is when that state accepts a condition, i want to dispatch new action (api request).

What is the right approach to accomplish this kind of problem?

Set a flag into state, and call new action in component after?
Somehow dispatch a function in reducer?

...?

Comment: "_when that state is valid_" - what is your definition for a valid state?

Comment: I meant when condition is met

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Redux Thunk allows you to dispatch multiple actions and dispatch asynchronous actions inside your action creators. For your scenario, you can do something like this:

```
function myAction() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    ...
    dispatch(firstAction);

    const state = getState();

    // Check your state conditions from first action here.
    dispatch(secondAction);
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try your solution, looks promising.

Answer (score 3):

In this case you could use library [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga).
Using redux-saga, you'll be able to create a saga that you call from a component like actions. In the saga you will be able to call several redux-actions. If your state will be valid from the saga, you can call the API request.
A popular alternative to [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) is also [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk).

Comment: Can you provide some sequence diagram for my scenario using thunk?

Comment: Sorry, I have never used thunk, i have used redux-saga, but i wrote about thunk, becouse i know this library can handle too this case.